# Operator Overloading a C struct

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I want to be able to create an assignment operator for a C structure (`struct tm` in `<time.h>`/ `std::tm` in `<ctime>`)  that I'm using in my C++ code. It's not necessary for my program, I am only wondering if it's possible to override. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

in header file tm_operators.hpp:

```
#ifndef tm_operators_hpp
#define tm_operators_hpp

#include <ostream>
#include <ctime>

static inline bool operator== (const std::tm &dt1, const std::tm &dt2 ) {
    return (dt1.tm_yday == dt2.tm_yday and dt1.tm_year == dt2.tm_year);
} /* Works fine */

static inline bool operator!= (const std::tm &dt1, const std::tm &dt2) {
    return not operator== (dt1, dt2);
}  /* Works fine */

static inline bool operator< (const std::tm &dt1, const std::tm &dt2) { ... } /* Works fine */

static inline bool operator> (const std::tm &dt1, const std::tm &dt2) {
    return operator< (dt2, dt1);
} /* Works fine */

static inline bool operator<= (const std::tm &dt1, const std::tm &dt2) {
    return not operator> (dt1, dt2);
} /* Works fine */

static inline bool operator>= (const std::tm &dt1, const std::tm &dt2) {
    return not operator< (dt1, dt2);
} /* Works fine */

static inline std::ostream & operator<< (std::ostream &os, const std::tm &dt) {
    char buff[11]; /* 11 characters in "dd/mm/YYYY\0" */
    std::strftime (buff, 11, "%d/%m/%Y", &dt);
    return os << buff;
} /* Works fine */

static inline std::tm & operator= (std::tm &dt, const char * str) {
    strptime (str, "%d/%m/%Y", &dt);
    return dt;
} /* This requires it to be part of the original struct which I can't modify */

#endif /* tm_operators_hpp */
```

The error I'm getting is `Overloaded 'operator=' must be a non-static member function`.
I don't have access to the class definition, so is there some way I can set this operator?

Comment: this talk goes into great details on why not to do it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BWvSSsKCiAw

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. As the error says, `operator=` has to be a member function. Them's [the rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators).

For that particular case, you could make a function instead that returns a new `tm` by value. But I see you are trying to implement lots of other operators too.

In general you should try to avoid overloading operators for types that aren't yours. That way madness lies.

Why not create your own class that *wraps* `tm` and has all the added functionality you want?